# Is this a valid encoding of a tree structure using set theory and a valid way to extract the leaves from it?

Tags: trees, sets, transitivity

I'm looking to formally define a tree and then extract the leaves from it in a concise way.
Does this look ok?
What is the best way of doing this?

$
Y = \{a,b,c,d,e,f,g\} \\
R = \{a \mapsto b, a \mapsto d, d \mapsto e, d \mapsto f, f \mapsto g\} \ \text{, where R is a relation on Y.} \\ 
R^+ = \{a \mapsto b, a \mapsto d, d \mapsto e, d \mapsto f, a \mapsto e, a \mapsto f, a \mapsto g\} \ \text{, where $R^+$ is the transitive closure of R.} \\
leaves = \{x \in range(R^+) \mid \ x \notin dom(R^+) \}
$

Comment: why you need $R^+$?

Comment: To be honest im not sure why I did that, its redundant

Comment: Also i made a typo it should be x and not R(x)

Answer (score 2):

How about this: $leaves = Y \setminus Preimage(R)$

Comment: Is this the same as $leaves = \{x \in range(R) \mid \ x \notin dom(R) \}
$

Comment: @newlogic No, it is different. Domain of $R$ is basically the entire set $Y$. Whereas, preimage of $R$ is a subset of the domain; it contains those elements that actually participate in the relation $R$. See [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Preimage/Relation#:~:text=The%20preimage%20of%20Y%20under,of%20Y%20under%20R%E2%88%921%3A&text=If%20no%20element%20of%20Y,1%5BY%5D%3D%E2%88%85) for a formal definition.